# Jquery ajax Post is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have used ajax post without form. When I click submit button it should get the values of other fields. Post request is not being sent and neither output is being shown. It is returning this error `Unexpected identifier`

**Here are the input fields**

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="center-block Ename" placeholder="Enter you name">
            <textarea class="center-block" name="message" id="message" rows="1" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
            <input class="center-block sendBtn" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

**This is the ajax request.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var interval = setInterval($('#submit').click(function(){
            var values = {
                'name': document.getElementById('name').value,
                'message': document.getElementById('message').value
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "chat.php",
                data: values,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#chat").html(data);
                }
            });

        }),1000);

    });
```

It is sending request to this php page

```
<?php
include 'db.php';


//Here post data is being assigned to variables
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO chat(`name`, `message`) VALUES('$name', '$message')";
        $queryInsertRun = mysqli_query($con, $queryInsert);
        if(!$queryInsertRun){
            echo mysqli_error($con);
        }



//Here is the output which should be shown

$query = "SELECT * FROM `chat` ORDER BY `name` AND `message` DESC ";
$queryRun = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryRun)){
$name = $row['name'];
$message = $row['message'];
?>
    <span class="name" style="font-weight: bold"><?php echo  $name?>:</span>
    <span class="message"><?php echo  $message.'<br>'?></span>
    <hr>
<?php
}
?>
```

I want to know that why is this not working.

Comment: I think the problem is about returned data, can you comment this line `$("#chat").html(data);` and tell if you still get the error or not?

Comment: Is the problem at client-side or server side? Is there any error message? Please add more information.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your JSON Data is not valid.

```
var data = JSON.stringify(values);
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: data,
  dataType: "html" // read about dataType
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
function ajaxcall()
{
console.log('i am called');
        var values = {
            'name': document.getElementById('name').value,
            'message': document.getElementById('message').value
        };

             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "chat.php",
                data: values,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#chat").html(data);
                }
            });

}

$(document).ready(function(){
var id = setInterval(function() {
   ajaxcall();
}, 1000);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/116/

Answer (score 1):

You want to display data if you clicked submit button , use simple click function . Using setInterval can't help you for clicking submit .
**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            var values = {
                'name': document.getElementById('name').value,
                'message': document.getElementById('message').value
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "chat.php",
                data: values,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#chat").html(data);
                }
            });

        });
      });
```